# How do I delete songs on my iphone using Windows version of iTunes?

Tags: itunes, windows, library

I have an iPhone 8+ and use the Windows version of iTunes. There are all these songs my son purchased thru iTunes showing up on my iPhone. How do I get these listings off my iPhone?

Note: The songs are not physically on the iPhone, but listed as downloadable. I don't want them listed at all.

Comment: The songs are not physically on the iPhone, but listed as downloadable. I don't want them listed at all.

Comment: Maybe try to turn off sync?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to see only your downloaded songs, at least on iOS 13 and newer:

## Method 1

1. Launch the Settings app.
2. Scroll down to the "Music" section and click on it.
3. Deselect the "Show all purchases" option.

This should now only show your local downloads.

## Method 2

1. Launch the Music app on your iPhone and click on the "Library" icon in the bottom menu bar.
2. In the top right corner, click on "Edit".
3. A customizable list with checkmark circles should appear. One of the categories that you can select is "Downloaded", which – as the name suggests – shows only the songs that are stored locally on your phone. You'll also see another category called "Songs". This category shows *all* of your songs (both in the cloud and the ones stored locally on your phone).
4. Uncheck the "Songs" category and check the "Downloaded" category.
5. Click "OK" in the top right corner of the screen to close the list. You should now see only your downloaded songs whenever you click on the "Downloaded" category.

And if you want to see all your purchases once more (including those that haven't been downloaded), you can simply select the "Songs" category instead of the "Downloaded" category – that is if you haven't disabled the "Show all purchases" option in Settings.

Comment: The first option didn’t work at all. The second option only works related to music purchased/ downloaded from iTunes. Most of the music I loaded from my own music library and it only shows along with all the other music I don’t want to see.

Answer (score 0):

Get your son and yourself separate Apple IDs. They aren't meant for sharing.

Answer (score -1):

The Apple Support page shows how to hide the purchases in your purchase history. This should hide even the iCloud streaming copy.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208167#hide

This one covers how to delete the downloaded copies:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204343

Comment: [Link-only answers are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) and puts you at risk of downvotes.  Include the important info within the answer.  This helps during indexing so search results are more accurate.